# I need to compare two files f1.txt and f2.txt and obtain the common elements?

Tags: awk, compare

I need to compare two files f1.txt and f2.txt and obtain the common elements, for this case i am lookin to match the first element of each line to print the whole line attached with the common elements?

f1.txt

```
3
4
5
```

f2.txt

```
1AAAAAA
2BBBBBB
3CCCCCC
4DDSDDDD
5EEEEEE
6FFFFFFF
7GGGGG
5EHHH
```

Expected result:

```
3CCCCCC
4DCCCCC
5EEEEEEE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
    a[$1];
    next
}
{
    split($1,b,"") ;
    if( b[1] in a && !c[b[1]] ) {
        print $1;
        c[b[1]]=1
    }
}' f1.txt f2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v FS= 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $1 in a{print; delete a[$1]}' f1.txt f2.txt
3CCCCCC
4DDSDDDD
5EEEEEE
```

The above will work in GNU awk and any other awk that splits records into fields of individual characters when FS is null. With other awks use substr($0,1,1).